# get the argument for this complex number

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

[image]

I rationalized and I obtained:

[image]

I get: $|z| = 2^6 = 64$

But $\arg(z) = 2 + \sqrt{3}$ ?

Comment: Are you confusing the modulus with the argument?

Comment: I just wanted to calculate also the modulus.

Comment: This is dangerous: you should **forget** the $\arctan(y/x)$ formula.

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks for your observation. I would love to continue my 'stupid' demonstration using the rationalization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{3}-i=2e^{-i\pi/6}$ and $1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}$, $\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{1+i}=\sqrt{2}e^{-5i\pi/12}$ and $z=2^6e^{-5i\pi}=-64$, which has modulus $64$, argument $\pi$.

Comment: Could you explain from z = -64 why the argument = arctg ( y / x ) =  π ?

Comment: @Akhtubir [Don't use $\arctan$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand now. I would like also to finish my demonstration using the rationalization.

Comment: @Akhtubir I mean, you could evaluate $\frac{3-i}{1+i}$ in Cartesian form and *then* verify it's $\sqrt{2}e^{-5i\pi/12}$, and take the rest from there. But... do you *know* the sine and cosine of $5\pi/12$ radians, i.e. of $75^\circ$? [You can get those](https://math.wikia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_constants#15.C2.B0:_dodecagon) from the sines and cosines of $15^\circ$.